# Simple VBscript for file rename. Error on conditional

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to rename a bunch of files with a conditional based on the file length. This is my code:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder(".\")

For Each File In Folder.Files

    sNewFile = File.Name

    If (sNewFile.Len < 8) Then
        sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile, "Slide_", "Mod2_P4_I2_0")
    Else
        sNewFile = Replace(sNewFile, "Slide_", "Mod2_P4_I2_")
    End If

    If (sNewFile <> File.Name) Then
        File.Move (File.ParentFolder + "\" + sNewFile)
    End If

Next
```

I'm getting this error on the first `If` statement:

> Object required: sNewFile

I guess I can't use 'len' on that object, but how else can I get the filename length for my conditional? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Len` function in VBScript:

> **Len**(*string* | *varname*)

Here's the VBA reference for the function for your information: [Len function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/len-function)

The following should work in your code:

```
If Len(sNewFile) < 8 Then
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the question as answered using the gray checkmark on the left of the answer when you get a chance.